# Didn't Pass Final Course for Undergraduate Degree - Already Have Full Time Job

Tags: undergraduate, graduation

Unfortunately I failed the last class I needed to get my undergraduate degree- even after walking on stage in front of my whole family. I emailed the professor back and forth to no avail and even applied to repeal the grade with the chair of my school (didn't work). This course is only offered during working hours for me and I don't think it can be done online. I am in panic mode and don't have a clue what to do at this point. Theres no way this is the first time this has ever happened to someone? Does anyone have any advice on what I should be doing? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6):

You're going to have to find a way to retake that class, or an acceptable substitute, if you want to get your degree.  So that's the starting point.

I would suggest you begin by speaking to your academic advisor.  They will know about possible options for retaking the class, or other classes you might be able to take as a substitute.  You can also ask about the possibility of taking an equivalent class through another university (which might include online options) and transferring the credit - but be sure to get the specific course approved by your university in advance.

Ultimately, you might have to consider rearranging your work schedule, or even looking for a different job with more flexible hours, in order to retake the class.  Which is more important to you in the long term, this specific job, or having a college degree?

(Another thing to keep in mind - if you were offered your current job on condition of having a degree, you would likely be obligated to inform your employer that you haven't yet graduated.  If that's the case, then going on with your current job and forgetting about the failed course may not be an option anyway.)

Comment: Definitely try to get the degree though! I've seen stunted careers because of similar situations where they never finished up.

Answer (score 2):

You have to work this out with the school. No one else has any authority to help you. Talk to someone in the department or at the Dean's level to find out your options. They will have some incentive to help, most likely. But you may have to go through a painful journey to find a suitable ending.